# Not able to set image icon for Java Swing Application, when running from JAR

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I set the icon image for my Java Application using the following code :

```
setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication8/images/Bravo_Logo.png")));
```

When I run it using NetBeans it runs properly, but when run using JAR built from Netbeans, it fails saying :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at javaapplication8.Bravo_Startup.<init>(Bravo_Startup.java:51)
        at javaapplication8.Bravo_Startup$5.run(Bravo_Startup.java:329)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.
            doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Examine the Jar content and check the icon is where you expect it to be. Then check the case of the entire path. The difference between `images` & `Images` might not mean a problem on a file system (e.g. Windows) but it is important for accessing case sensitive paths, like here.

Comment: Really amazing to note....I have been cracking my head for this one for the past 2 days... The problem finally being "Bravo_Logo.PNG" instead of "Bravo_Logo.png"....Thank you Thompson...

Comment: You;re welcome. Glad you got it sorted. :)